# Number of evaluations of function in where clause of query

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, database-performance

Let's have a look at this select:

```
SELECT table1.x,table2.y 
FROM   table1 
JOIN   table2 ON (table1.z = table2.z)
WHERE  table1.id = myfunction(12324);
```

How many times will be myfunction called in Oracle database? Parameter of this function is a contstant number value, it is not dependent on row values.

I know some databases will evaluate this function only once, but I couldn't find what will happen in Oracle.

Comment: It depends. Obviously, `dbms_random.value()` is evaluated as much times as it is called while `sysdate` evaluated once. You may declare function as `deterministic` to enforce it to be treated as constant for constant input, then Oracle will try to reduce its evaluation.

Comment: The myfunction is not deterministic, and cannot be changed to determinictic. So in that case, it is evaluated for each row?

Comment: Look at the EXPLAIN PLAN when you run it. I would assume it is only run once as there would be no need to run it more than once

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mark the function as `DETERMINISTIC`, it will fire for every row in the table you are comparing it to, so that'd be the # of rows in `table1`.

If you mark it as `DETERMINISTIC`, it should fire once regardless of which table you are comparing it to because it caches the result and sees that the parameter never changes. If instead of a literal you were to pass in a column value, it would execute once per distinct parameter value.

This is true whether you use it in the `WHERE` clause or the `SELECT` clause.

If you can't mark it as deterministic, you can force it with a *materialized* CTE:

```
  WITH fx AS (SELECT /*+ materialize */ myfunction(12324) fxval FROM dual)
    SELECT table1.x,table2.y 
    FROM   table1
    JOIN   table2 ON (table1.z = table2.z)
    WHERE  table1.id = (SELECT fxval FROM fx)
```

To test, simply add a `dbms_output.put_line('executing...');` line in your function and try various queries with it (limiting your rows to something reasonably small like in the single digits, or the dbms output will take forever to dequeue). You can then inspect the # of dbms output calls to see how many times it actually fired.

Comment: WITH sel_1 AS (
SELECT myfunction(12324) AS myfunctionresult from dual
)
SELECT table1.x,table2.y 
FROM   table1 
JOIN   table2 ON (table1.z = table2.z)
JOIN   sel_1 ON (sel_1.myfunctionresult = table1.id)

Would this force it to evaluate only once?

Comment: Only if it materializes. You can force it with `WITH sel_1 AS ( SELECT /*+ materialize */ myfunction(12324) AS myfunctionresult from dual ) . . .` Edited my answer with this info.

Comment: @PaulW Another possibility is to wrap it with locally declared function `with function some_name(param type) as ...` that is marked as `deterministic`. It's available since 12.2 as far as I remember. See example here: https://dbfiddle.uk/LkBWMto6